# How do you close a vue-material md-menu?

Tags: vuejs2, material-design

I'd like to call close on a `mouseleave` event on an `md-menu` component. I'm using version 0.7.4 of the `vue-material`library, and using [this documentation](https://vue-material-old.netlify.com/releases/v0.7.5/#/components/menu) it says that there is a close method.

How do I call this method? I've tried the following:

```
<md-menu md-size="1" ref="aRef" id="aRef">
  <div @mouseleave="this.$refs['aRef'].close()">
  ...other stuff...
</md-menu>
```

When I run this I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aRef' of undefined
```

I'm guessing this is something to do with the component not being available at creation time. What's the correct way of doing this?

I should say that the `md-menu` is actually nested inside another `md-menu` (which seems to work ok from a functional perspective). Not sure if that screws up the event hierarchy.

Comment: have you tried to do this in a methods function? @mouseleave="close(this)"

Comment: @Gerfried same error I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across the solution for this one while I was trying to solve a different problem (how to close any other menus before opening another).

Your problem is that you can't use `this` inline in the html template. You need to send the event to a method and then call it...

```
<md-menu 
    ref="aRef"
    @mouseleave="closeMenu"
>
    // menu contents

</md-menu>
```

Then in your script section:

```
methods: {
    closeMenu() {
        this.$refs['aRef'].close();
    }
}
```